# Setting up bounds for the integral $(\int_{U}|f(x,y)|^{2}dxdy)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the text "Functions of a Complex Variable" by Robert E.Grenne and Steven G. Knartz I'm having the trouble with figuring out a method of attack for $\text{Proposition (1.1)}$ specifically getting the integral $(\int_{U}|f(x,y)|dxdy)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ into a more manageable form, may I have a hint to achieve this ?

$\text{Proposition (1.1)}$

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and let $K$ be a compact subset $U$. Show that there is a constant $C$ $\text{(depending on U and K)}$ such that if $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, then in $(1.2)$

$(1.2)$

$$\sup_{K}|f| \leq C \cdot \big(\int_{U}|f(x,y)|^{2}dxdy \big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: An answer for the case of a disc contained in a bigger disc can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021451/l-infty-norm-is-bounded-by-l2-norm-for-holomorphic-functions. You can use geometric argument to carry this over to your case (cover $K$ by discs of sufficiently small radius and choose a finite subcover).

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Thomas :>).

Comment: @Thomas would you mind writing that as an answer?

Comment: @barto no -- if it helps..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer for the case of a disc contained in a bigger disc can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021451/l-infty-norm-is-bounded-by-l2-norm-for-holomorphic-functions).

You can use a geometric argument to carry this over to your case. To this end,cover $K$
by discs of sufficiently small radius and then choose a finite subcover.